# Expanding $a^{ab} - 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

It seemes to me that it is truth after checking on $2$ examples but need to be sure.
So, let's assume that $n=ab$ and $a>b$

$$a^n-1=a^{ab}-1=(a^a-1)(a^{a(b-1)}+a^{a(b-2)}+\cdots+1)$$

Is written above statement true or not?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to prove? What is $\ast$ here? Do you mean multiplication?

Comment: @Saegusa ok, done

Comment: Do you know how to factor $x^b-1$ when $b>1$ is an integer?

Comment: Use the finite geometric series formula $1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$, with $x=a^a$ and $n=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $b$ is a positive integer, then $a-1$ is a factor of the polynomial $a^b-1$, since $1$ is a root. Thus we have

$$a^b-1=(a-1)(a^{b-1}+a^{b-2}+...+a^2+a+1)$$

You can check by expanding the product on the right and observe the cancellations. Then let $a\rightarrow a^{a}$ and we are done.

---

We also have

$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$

See [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Recognizable_patterns)